# Uploading multiple image to server without accessing same session with two ajax call simultaneously ?

Tags: session, vue.js, session-cookies, vue-resource

I am trying to upload multiple image using ajax call, but when two ajax call request same session, its , my login get logs out, so I am trying to upload it in synchronous way using ajax.
How i should upload it with ajax with making async

Comment: Please add more details (including code) of what you're trying to achieve and what you've already tried that isn't working.

Comment: Chrome: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Chrome: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated
>   because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For
>   more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Since Synchronous XMLHttpRequest is **deprecated** in Chrome and Firefox, you can do something that feels synchronous like this:

```
async function sendRequest() {
    let response = await this.$http.get('/someUrl')
    console.log(response.body)
}
```

Comment: I am trying to upload multiple image using ajax, but when two ajax call share the same session, server logged out my session, so I am trying to upload it sync-wise. Any luck ?